# connecting logstash with elasticsearch (not embedded)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to connect logstash (1.3.3) with elasticsearch (0.9+) on ubuntu12.  I am not using the embedded option (it works).  I am trying to get the standalone setup working.  I am able to launch elasticsearch.  I have tried to connect to elasticsearch (tried both 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1) via the logstash.conf file but the connection does not appear to work.  Any thoughts on troubleshooting will be helpful.

**logstash.conf**

```
output {
  stdout {codec => rubydebug }
  elasticsearch { host => "0.0.0.0" }
```

I can confirm via netstat that elasticsearch is listening on 0.0.0.0 (I have tried setting elasticsearch to run on 127.0.0.1 and switched logstash conf as well but that did not work either).

I can access elasticsearch on port 9200 via the browser.

Update:
Pilot error - there was an issue in my elasticsearch.yml file that prevented discovery (I had added **node.local:true** during testing).

Comment: Which version of ElasticSearch are you running? The `elasticsearch` plugin is extremely picky ([documentation for LS 1.3.3](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/outputs/elasticsearch) suggests ES 0.90.9 *only*). The [`elasticsearch_http` plugin](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/outputs/elasticsearch_http) is more tolerant about versions. As a note about IPs, listening on 0.0.0.0 typically means an application is listening on all IPs (in case your machine has more than one), sending to 127.0.0.1 means you're sending to yourself.

Comment: thanks - was mostly pilot error - I had added a config in elasticsearch.yml that prevent discovery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pilot error - there was an issue in my elasticsearch.yml file that prevented discovery (I had added **node.local:true** during testing).